# sharepoint restricting images in iframe from showing in IE

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint

I have a Page Viewer web part in SharePoint 2013 pointing to a relative URL (html file) on the same server, which is displayed in an iFrame. In Firefox the page is displayed fine, but in IE10 (and Edge, 9, 8, ect) the images are just error 'x' boxes. I've been reading all morning about IE zones and such but I haven't been able to find any solution. I have copy/pasted the URL for the image directly into the browser and I can confirm the link is correct. Can anyone help? Please let me know if I've missed including any information.

Here is what the page looks like:

[image]

EDIT: I just checked the network traffic for page during image loading and all 3 came back with a 200 result and correct data size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed all my images to JPG and they started working. I can't explain why, but it solved my issue.

Leaving this open for a bit to see if anyone can shed some light.